# How would you print out the character of that string at the index of the string for a given array of Strings

Tags: java, eclipse

Sorry my question is kind of hard to understand. So in a array such as
String []arr =  {"abs, "def", "ghi"};
I want to know how it can print out this
a 
e
i

this is my code that i have tried to write but failed.

```
public static void printCharsAt(String[] arr) { 
    System.out.println("how many inputs do you want in your array");
    String array[] = {"hello", "Ap", "CS"};        
    System.out.println("What term of the array do you want, do you wan the first, 2nd, or third");
    tnt char = kb.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println(array[char]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without any bounds checking:

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    System.out.println(arr[i].charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop through each String in the array. You may use `for each` loop in Java or the traditional `for` loop. Once you get a String, You can use the `charAt()` method of `String` class to obtain the character at a particular position. Don't forget the `length` method also, It may come in handy.  No code,  since it is homework :)

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention on [charAt(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method